# Torch.nn.Transformer Example Code Throwing Tensor Shape Errors

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model

I was trying to implement a Transformer model with Pytorch and was experimenting with the example from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/word_language_model), which was linked from [here in the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#transformer-layers), and ran into a problem within the PositionalEncoding class, found within model.py.

The code for the class's `__init__()` function is as follows:

```
def __init__(self, d_model, dropout=0.1, max_len=5000):
    super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)

    pe = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model)
    position = torch.arange(0, max_len, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
    div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2).float() * (-math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
    pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
    pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
    pe = pe.unsqueeze(0).transpose(0, 1)
    self.register_buffer('pe', pe)
```

This code, ran with d_model = 103, threw the following error on the forth last line (`pe[:, 0::2] =`...):

RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (52) must match the existing size (51) at non-singleton dimension 1.  Target sizes: [5000, 52].  Tensor sizes: [5000, 51]

I've found this error fairly impenetrable and haven't had much success writing my own similarly effective implementation. 
My first guess would be that this is a problem with version changes within Python/PyTorch, but it could of course be something else I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
0:51:2 instead of 0::2
```

> 0::2 will generate this -> [0,2,4,...,until the end of Elements]

Comment: Managed to get this working by using ```:d_model-1:2``` to get the size 51 tensor. Not sure why this wasn't present in the doc, but making a change here did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do like this:

```py
class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, d_model, max_len=1000):
    super().__init__()
    self.d_model = d_model
    self.max_len = max_len
  
  def forward(self):
    pos = torch.arange(self.max_len).view(-1, 1).float()
    pe = torch.arange(self.d_model).repeat(self.max_len, 1).float()
    pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(pos / (10000 ** (2 * pe[:, 0::2] / self.d_model)))
    pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(pos / (10000 ** (2 * pe[:, 1::2] / self.d_model)))
    return pe.unsqueeze(0)
```

and when summing limit with slice:

```py
x + pe[:, :x.size(1)])
```

Comment: Ohh you already `used max_length`, so you just need to slice it (2nd code)

Answer (score 0):

This error is because your `d_model` is an **odd number**. You can see the shape of `div_term` is depend on `torch.arange(0, d_model, 2)`, in your case the shape is 51.

However, the shape of `pe[:, 0::2]` is 52.

This usually doesn't happen because in the Transformer model, before the tensor was put in the PositionalEncoding, it will be put in a embedding layer to **embedded** into a shape which is usually an **even number** (512, 128, etc.). when the  `d_model` is an even number, the shape of `pe[:, 0::2]` and the shape of `div_term` will be equal.

So in your case, You can correct this by

- make your `d_model` an even number (by embedding your input into an even number dimension);
- or make your `div_term` equals to `pe[:, 0::2]` by modify the shape of `div_term`

```
def __init__(self, d_model, dropout=0.1, max_len=5000):
    super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)

    pe = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model)
    position = torch.arange(0, max_len, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
    div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model-1, 2).float() * (-math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
    pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
    div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2).float() * (-math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
    pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
    pe = pe.unsqueeze(0).transpose(0, 1)
    self.register_buffer('pe', pe)
```

PS: if you modify `pe[:, 0::2]` into `pe[:, 0:d_model-1:2]`, of course it will work because you make it equals to 51, just like `div_term`. But it also means the last dimension of `pe` won't be assigned any value, it will still be zero. This means the last dimension of input won't be Positional Encoded.